# passing values from onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Given the following code, how do I pass the values of day, month and year from the onCLick form to generate the variable $date in the script?

```
<head>

<!--

/* Generate day name script */

$date = "day. .month. .year";

function inDate() {
    s = $date;
    if (s != "" && s != null) determineDay(s);
    alert ("Name date is "+$wDay+);
}

//-->

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" value="day" id="day" />
<input type="text" value="month" id="month" />
<input type="text" value="year" id="year" />

<form name='f1'><input value='Generate Day name' onclick='inDate()' type='button'></form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be what you are doing and should help you get started:

```js
var date, wDay; //global vars

function determineDay(date){
  // set global var wDay
  wDay = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'
         , 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' 
         ][ date.getUTCDay() ];
}

function inDate(){
  // Set global var date
  date = new Date( Date.UTC( +document.getElementById('year').value
                           ,  document.getElementById('month').value -1 //month is zero-based
                           , +document.getElementById('day').value
                           )        
                 );
  if( !isNaN(date) ){       // test for invalid date
    determineDay(date);
    alert(  'Name date is ' + wDay  );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="day" id="day" />
<input type="text" value="month" id="month" />
<input type="text" value="year" id="year" />

<form name="f1"><input value="Generate Day name" onclick="inDate()" type="button"></form>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the quick response. That almost works but I'm getting a result showing the day before the date I enter. So for 02 Apr 2015 I'm getting Wednesday instead of Thursday.